# How to check for duplicates in a a list before adding another number into it?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

So I have a task to do, which involves not using Sets or Maps. The task is to create a list of the intersection of two sorted Integer lists, and not have any duplicates added to that list. I've figured out the first part, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to check if the integer that is being added isn't already on the list?

I'm guessing some kind of a loop?

```
     public ArrayList<Integer> Intersection(ArrayList<Integer> A,   ArrayList<Integer> B) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (i != A.size() && j != B.size()) {
        if (A.get(i) < B.get(j)) {
            i ++;
        } 

        else if (A.get(i) > B.get(j)) {
            j ++;
        }

        else {
            result.add(A.get(i));
            i ++; j++;
        }

    }


    return result;
  }
 }
```

So with the code above I get the intersection, but it has duplicates, for example from an

list A [2, 2, 2, 3] and

list B [2, 2, 3, 4]

I get the result of [2, 2, 3] when the expected result is [2, 3]

Comment: Look at the [api docs for `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), and check out the `contains()` method.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I couldn't think of that. Everything is working now.

Comment: Build the result as a merge.  That way, duplicates are always obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Always code to interface
- Just need to add one check. Check comment in below code

  ```
  public static List<Integer> intersection(List<Integer> A, List<Integer> B) {
      List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;

      while (i != A.size() && j != B.size()) {
          if (A.get(i) < B.get(j)) {
              i++;
          }

          else if (A.get(i) > B.get(j)) {
              j++;
          }

          else {
              // If already contains item dont add again
              if (!result.contains(A.get(i))) {
                  result.add(A.get(i));
              }
              i++;
              j++;
          }

      }

      return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Integer> r = intersection(Arrays.asList(2, 2, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(2, 2, 3, 4));
      System.out.println(r);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList();
for (Integer a: A)
    if (B.contains(a))
        result.add(a);
return result;
```

You can optimise it if you want to perform less iterations. Go through the implementation of `List.contains()` method to have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have classic problem: merge two sorted list (this is final step of [MergeSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm). Just one modification - avoid duplicate:

```
public static List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> one, List<Integer> two) {
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>(one.size() + two.size());

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < one.size() || j < two.size(); ) {
        if (i < one.size() && one.get(i) <= two.get(j)) {
            if (res.isEmpty() || !res.get(res.size() - 1).equals(one.get(i)))
                res.add(one.get(i));
            i++;
        } else if (j < two.size()) {
            if (res.isEmpty() || !res.get(res.size() - 1).equals(two.get(j)))
                res.add(two.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```